# Creating a generic method to work on Collection Java to alter content of ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I want to create a generic method which can take ArrayList of Integer, Float, or any type which extends Number.

```
public void mulBy2(ArrayList<? extends Number> list) {
// I want to multiply the value of each element in list by 2
// and store it back in list
for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
  Double d =  al.get(i).doubleValue()*2;
  al.set(i,d); // Obvious error here says required ? extends Number
// how to solve this issue
}
}
```

if list was ArrayList with values [2,3,4] , my method should return or make the arrayList with values [4,6,8]
ArrayList with initially [1.2,3.4] should convert to [2.4,6.8]

Comment: OK, now we know what you want, but do you have a question?  We have no way of knowing what you do and do not know; you need to tell us what your actual difficulty is.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure we do know all of what you want or can assume.  In the full generality with which the problem is presently described, there is no type-safe solution in Java alone.  For example, if I define my own subclass of `Number` without any public constructor, and pass your method a nonempty `ArrayList` having that type parameter, then there is no way your method could perform the required work.

Comment: //I tried writing the method like public static void mul2(ArrayList<? extends Number) al ) { ... } .. Inside for loop from i = 0 to al.size()-1 , when i use Ial.get(i).intValue()*2 and try to set this new value like al.set(i, al.get(i).intValue()*2) ; i get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. A `<Number>` list filled with Double-s

Here is a quick fix:

```
public void mulBy2(List<Number> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      Double d =  list.get(i).doubleValue()*2;
      list.set(i,d);
    }
}
```

The fix consists of the following changes:

1. It's totally okay expect a `List<Number>`. A `List<Number>` can hold any mix of number, e.g. `Integer`, `Float`, `BigDecimal`.
2. It's better to code to a interface, e.g. `List` and not to an implementation, `ArrayList`.
3. Now we can simply add back the `Double` numbers.

There are a couple of problems with this code though:

1. All the doubled numbers are going to be Doubles.
2. You can't pass a `List<Integer>` parameter anymore.
3. This method can't handle `BigDecimal` -s which have a large value

#### 2. Bound subtype with `insanceof` checks.

So let's write another fix:

```
public <T extends Number> void mulBy2Attempt2(List<T> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        list.set(i, multiplyBy2(list.get(i)));
    }
}

private <T extends Number> T multiplyBy2(T num) {
    if (num instanceof BigDecimal) {
        return (T) ((BigDecimal) num).multiply(new BigDecimal(2));
    }
    if (num instanceof BigInteger) {
        return (T) ((BigInteger) num).multiply(new BigInteger("2"));
    }
    if (num instanceof Long) {
        return (T) new Long(num.longValue() * 2);
    }
    if (num instanceof Integer) {
        return (T) new Integer(num.intValue() * 2);
    }
    if ((num instanceof Double)) {
        return (T) new Double(num.doubleValue() * 2);
    }
    if (num instanceof Float) {
        return (T) new Float(num.floatValue() * 2);
    }
    if (num instanceof Byte) {
        return (T) new Byte((byte) (num.byteValue() * 2));
    }
    if (num == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Cannot multiply a null-number by two");
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot handle a number of " + num.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " yet.");
}
```

This is really cool. Because of the bound type `<T extends Number>`, it can accept any kind of list, like `List<AtomicInteger>` or `List<Number>`. This solution has a couple of drawbacks though:

1. It relies heavily on `instanceof` checks
2. It can't possibly handle all the `Number` subclasses because anybody is free to implement a new `Number` subclass, and then you're done.

#### 3. Let the caller decide how to multiply by two

We can use lambdas to put this burden on the caller:

```
public <T extends Number> void mulBy2Attempt3(List<T> list, Function<T,T> multiplier) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        list.set(i, multiplier.apply(list.get(i)));
    }
}
```

So you can call it like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
mulBy2Attempt3(list, n -> n * 2);
System.out.println(list);
```

#### 4. Using Streams and `map`

What we have now is almost like the `map` function:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);

List<Integer> list2 = list.stream().map(n -> n * 2).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list2);
```

This is slightly different because it won't modify the original list.

Now you have several options. Based on your requirements you can decide which way to go.

Answer (score 1):

We do not want to do your homework, but I think the question should be answered because it can be useful for future visitors. The solution should include the following:

- iterate the elements
- get the `class` of the current element
- call the corresponding method to the `class` of the current element to get its value, so if it is `Integer`, `invoke` the `intValue` of the object via reflection, multiply it with 2 and set the corresponding element of the list to the new value

Useful to know:

1. Corresponding methods are: `intValue`, `longValue`, `floatValue`, `doubleValue`, `byteValue` and `shortValue`, the names of the classes more-or less correlate to them, like `Double`, `Float`, etc. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html
2. You can get the `class` of an `Object` by calling its `getClass` method. Its name can be obtained by calling the getEnclosingClass of the resulting `class`. Example:

`Class<?> enclosingClass = getClass().getEnclosingClass();
if (enclosingClass != null) {
  System.out.println(enclosingClass.getName());
} else {
  System.out.println(getClass().getName());
}`

3. With reflection you can call invoke to call a method. Example:

`Class<?> c = Class.forName("class name");
Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("method name", parameterTypes);
method.invoke(objectToInvokeOn, params);`

Good luck!